# height as parent and position inside navbar

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-position

I've modified for the third time, and now it looks clearer. Here is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/3w2gdfqp/

### html

```
<div id="navWrap">  
      <div class="mainContainer">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-md-18">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">OUR PHILOSOPHY</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">OFFERS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FINE WINE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>  
            </ul>
            <div class="searchBoxContainer col-md-5 pull-right">
              <div id="searchOurWines" class="blackBox">
                  <span id="textSearchBox" class="textInBox">SEARCH OUR WINES</span>
                  <span id="iconSearchBox">
                    <span class="icon-icn-bottle"></span>   
                    <a href=""><span id="arrowSearch" class="icon-icn-sort_down"></span>  
                      <span id="arrowSearch2" class="icon-icn-sort_up"></span></a>   
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>   
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->  
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### css

```
/*Navigation bar*/
#navbar{
    padding:0;
}
.navbar{
    border-radius:0;
    min-height:40px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default{
     border:0;
     margin:0;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
#navWrap{
    background-color:#808080;
}
#arrowSearch2{
    display:none;
}
.searchBoxContainer{
    border:1px solid pink;
}
```

as you see, the SEARCH OUR WINES, doesn't have the same height as the navigation bar, and I've tried everything I could!!

Any suggestions??

thanksss

Comment: Please don't repeat questions (even with updates)... **Update the previous question**. In this case, you've already done it so I'd recommend **Deleting The Previous Question** after making sure you have covered all of the points that may have been raised in any comments there.

Answer (score 0):

See if the below one works :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">OUR PHILOSOPHY</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">OFFERS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">FINE WINE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">TOUR & TASTE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li><div class="searchBoxContainer col-md-5 pull-right">
                        <div id="searchOurWines">
                          <div id="containerSearch" class="blackBox">
                            <span id="textSearchBox" class="textInBox">SEARCH OUR WINES</span>
                            <span id="iconSearchBox">
                              <span class="icon-icn-bottle"></span>   
                              <a href=""><span id="arrowSearch" class="icon-icn-sort_down pull-right"></span>  
                                 <span id="arrowSearch2" class="icon-icn-sort_up pull-right"></span></a>   
                            </span>
                          </div>  
                        </div> 
                     </div>
                  </li>  
                </ul>
```

and shift the search box at right side by css if it is not already

Comment: thank you for answeing!

It moves everything so much around! And it is not ideal as I have to move the search box to different places depending of the screen size, so I need it in one block separated from the <ul> menu